# Какой синтаксис лучше использовать при написании React-компонентов: ES5 или ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Не так давно начал изучать React JS и у меня появился вопрос: какой синтаксис лучше всего использовать при написании React-компонентов: ES5 или ES6? И какое будет преимущество в зависимости от выбора?

Comment: Однохренственно. В принципе фейсбук больше любит es6-синтаксис и планирует когда-нибудь в далеком-далеком-далеком будущем задепрекейтить .createClass.  Практическая разница в том что реакт делает аутобиндинг методов для createClass и не делает для es6 классов, оставляя вам возможность накосячить

Comment: Это если вы говорите про разницу в создании компонента как es6 класс или React.createClass. Если же вопрос про то, использовать всякие стрелочки, spread операторы и прочий сахар, то да - использовать. Но это относится уже именно к js как таковому, а не к реакту.

Answer (score 2):

ES6. Документация написана в ES6, ES6 имеет не мало чего [нового](https://habrahabr.ru/company/plarium/blog/270353/), и на многое из ES6 заточен React.

Так же не забывай про сборщик (webpack, например) и будет тебе счастье